# Gazebo Hokuyo laser not working properly

Tags: gazebo, laser, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I´m trying to run some mapping experiments with a mobile robot on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine with ROS Kinetic and Gazebo 7.

What I did was to define a diff-drive with the following urdf:

https://github.com/JoseJaramillo/lucrezio_simulation_environments/blob/master/urdf/lucrezio.urdf.xacro

and then, to run the simulation I use this launch file:

https://github.com/JoseJaramillo/lucrezio_simulation_environments/blob/master/launch/robot.launch

by doing so, I get a strange behavior, that is, the robot is loaded correctly but from the laser scan it seems that it´s not able to sense objects:

https://ibb.co/PzXpQg9

Can you please explain me what could be the problem, please?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311548/gazebo-hokuyo-laser-not-working-properly/) by [JoseJaramillo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39210/josejaramillo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Try the using the non-GPU version of the laser.

Hello! I did that, it didn't work as expected.

However, I solved it by reinstalling-updating the NVIDIA drivers. works like a champ! Thank you anyway!

---

Originally posted by [JoseJaramillo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39210/josejaramillo/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the using the non-GPU version of the laser. Change the line

```
<sensor type="gpu_ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
```

to

```
<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
```

and replace

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
```

with

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
```

---

Originally posted by [lovelife](https://answers.ros.org/users/38340/lovelife/) with karma: 31 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lovelife](https://answers.ros.org/users/38340/lovelife/) on 2018-12-27**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/250556/hokuyo-laser-scanner-not-working-in-gazebo-using-ros-kinetic/?answer=256746#post-id-256746

**Comment by [utkuolcar](https://answers.ros.org/users/64419/utkuolcar/) on 2020-12-01**:
Thank you. Only this option worked for me.